# Where should I put the code that extracts all categories and make them viewable

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have (finally) managed to make a question form the way I want it to work. The last part is still missing: the categories the questions can belong to. I have made a question handler class that manages the persisting etc of the question, and I wonder if I should put it together with the other methods in that class?

There are 10 categories (just an ID and a description). I think I lack experience and knowledge to know exactly how I should organize and what belongs to a backing bean.

```
public abstract class QuestionHandler {

    @Inject
    protected QuestionServiceBean questionBean;

    @Inject
    protected Question question;
    protected List<Answer> answers;
    protected List<Category> categories;
    protected String correctAnswer;

    public void updateQuestion() {
        questionBean.updateQuestion(question);
    }

    public String persist() {               
        question.setAnswers(answers);
        question.setCategories(categories);
        questionBean.persistQuestion(question);
    }

    public void persistAsUserSubmitted() {
        question.setAnswers(answers);
        question.setCategories(categories);
        questionBean.persistAsUserSubmitted(question);
    }

    protected void addAnswerAlternative() {
        if (answers != null) {
            answers.add(new Answer());
        }
    }

    public abstract void init();

        // Removed the getters/setters for readability.

}
```

This class is ofcourse extended and has implemented the init method, but that is not important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logic is related to your *domain* then `CategoryServiceBean` is the right place to get categories from.

Comment: Is it usual to have one servicebean pr domain model? (I am learning, so it is maybe a stupid question)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right. You're exploding the model's properties in the controller.

```
protected Question question;
protected List<Answer> answers;
protected List<Category> categories;

public String persist() {               
    question.setAnswers(answers);
    question.setCategories(categories);
    questionBean.persistQuestion(question);
}

public void persistAsUserSubmitted() {
    question.setAnswers(answers);
    question.setCategories(categories);
    questionBean.persistAsUserSubmitted(question);
}
```

One would expect it more to be

```
protected Question question;

public String persist() {               
    questionBean.persistQuestion(question);
}

public void persistAsUserSubmitted() {
    questionBean.persistAsUserSubmitted(question);
}
```

werein you just reference the nested properties in the view by `#{bean.question.answers}` and `#{bean.question.categories}` instead of `#{bean.answers}` and `#{bean.categories}`.

As to the concrete question, I assume that you're talking about "available categories" which are to be used in `<f:selectItems>` and like? Yes, you can just put it in a separate (application scoped?) bean. But if it concerns the "selected categories", just bind it to the `Question` as `#{bean.question.categories}` as suggested before. E.g.

```html
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.question.categories}" converter="#{categoryConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.categories}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Please note that the converter is referenced by EL because I assume it to be a `@ManagedBean` or `@Named` as you want to use an `@EJB` inside it (based on your other quesiton).

Comment: But this is when the user makes a new question. There are no answers or categories accosiated with the question before that. I couldn't think of another way of doing it then.

Comment: I don't see how that can possibly form a problem. All you have to do is to do `new Question()` and make sure that the nested list properties are not `null`.

Comment: The categories are displayed in a select-menu. No categories are accosiated with the new question before that. I am unsure if I understand it. Should I make a new Question object, then two arraylists and bind those on the newly created question object as answers/categories?

Comment: As answered, if you're talking about "available categories" as in `<f:selectItems>`, then just put it in a separate bean. If it's static application wide data, then make the bean `@ApplicationScoped`. Otherwise make it `@RequestScoped` and leverage the caching job to JPA or whatever persistence layer you're using. See also the example which I updated in the answer.